# pyqt4 mouse release event not firing

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to track a mousepress and mouserelease event but the mouse release event is not recognized.

```
import sys, os

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *



class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.btn = QPushButton("Add Line")

        self.gv = QGraphicsView()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.gv.setScene(self.scene)
        self.gv.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing | QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)

        lay = QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn)
        lay.addWidget(self.gv)
        script_dir = sys.path[0]

        image_loc = os.path.dirname(script_dir) + '/testproject/configs/files/lena.png'
        print image_loc
        #self.p_item = self.scene.addPixmap(QPixmap("lena.png"))
        self.p_item = self.scene.addPixmap(QPixmap(image_loc))

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.add_line)

    def add_line(self, event):
        import pprint
        print pprint.pprint(dir(event))
        pass

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        print 'mouse press event = ', QMouseEvent.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        print 'mouse release event = ', QMouseEvent.pos()
        # cursor = QCursor()
        # print 'mouse release event = ', cursor.pos()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt the events are passed from the parents to the children, but not vice versa. In your case the event `mousePressEvent` starts in Widget, then you can move to `QPushButton` or `QGraphicsView`, let's assume it is in this case that it falls in `QGraphicsView` then it happens to your child widget called `viewport()`, this will be done until some widget accept the event, the same must happen with `mouseReleaseEvent`, but for an object to receive the `mouseReleaseEvent` must have accepted the `mousePressEvent` event, and the only one that has done so is the `viewport()` of `QGraphicsView`. The solution is to install an event filter to the `viewport()` of `QGraphicsView` as shown below.

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)    
        self.btn = QPushButton("Add Line")

        self.gv = QGraphicsView()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.gv.setScene(self.scene)
        self.gv.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing | QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)

        lay = QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn)
        lay.addWidget(self.gv)
        script_dir = sys.path[0]

        image_loc = os.path.dirname(script_dir) + '/testproject/configs/files/lena.png'
        print(image_loc)
        #self.p_item = self.scene.addPixmap(QPixmap("lena.png"))
        self.p_item = self.scene.addPixmap(QPixmap(image_loc))

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.add_line)

        self.gv.viewport().installEventFilter(self) # <----

    def add_line(self, event):
        import pprint
        print(pprint.pprint(dir(event)))

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.gv.viewport():
            if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                print('mouse press event = ', event.pos())
            elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                print('mouse release event = ', event.pos())

        return QWidget.eventFilter(self, obj, event)
```